# C++ Operator overloading with templated types are giving me errors

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++17

I have been struggling with how to make a minimal verifiable example of this but I cannot think of how to do it. I have two Expected Types that I am trying to add together. The expected can be a data type such as int, double, etc. Or it can be an exception. In theory, I should be able to add the data type with an exception and it will be able to run the program just fine, when I ask for the value. It should return the exception without crashing the program.

Whenever I try to run this program I get hundreds of lines of error messages that I don't even know where to begin, the one error I see is `no matching function for call to 'operator+(double&,double&)` I do not know if this is correct either, because I want to add two Expected's together, I do not want to add the types themselves. In the end, I want to add an Expected, and get returned and Expected.

I am really stuck here, I was told that my `apply` function has been implemented incorrectly but I honestly cannot see why that is the case. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <functional>
#include <variant>

template<typename T>
class Expected
{

public:
    Expected(T t) : state(t), valid(true){} 
    Expected(std::exception_ptr e) : state(e), valid(false){}   
    Expected(std::exception e) : state(std::make_exception_ptr(e)), valid(false){}  

    T value() const 
    {
        if(valid) return std::get<T>(state);
        std::rethrow_exception(std::get<std::exception_ptr>(state));
    }

    bool isValid()
    {
        if(valid) return true;
        return false;
    }

    template<typename U>
    Expected<U> apply(std::function<U(T)> f)
    {
        if(!valid) return std::get<std::exception_ptr>(state);
        try
        {
            return f(std::get<T>(state));
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            return std::current_exception();
        }
    }
private:

    std::variant<T, std::exception_ptr> state;
    bool valid;

};

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, Expected<T> e)
{
    try
    {
        o << e.value();
    }
    catch(std::exception &a)
    {
        o << a.what();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        o << "Unexpected Error";
    }

    return o;
}

template<typename T, typename V>
auto operator+(Expected<T> t, Expected<V> v)
{
    return t.apply([&](T myT){return operator+(myT,v);});
}
template<typename T, typename V>
auto operator+(Expected<T> t, V v)
{
    return t.apply([&](T myT){return operator+(myT,v);});
}
template<typename T, typename V>
auto operator+(V v, Expected<T> t)
{
    return t.apply([&](T myT){return operator+(v,myT);});
}

int main()
{
    Expected<int> a = 1;
    Expected<int> b = 2;

    std::cout << a + b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That `valid` is not strictly necessary here. You can call `variant::which` to get the index of type of the stored value.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin which valid? `isValid()` or the boolean `valid` all together?

Comment: `valid` data member is unnecessary because it can be computed as `state.which() == 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a reduced example of the first problem:

```
int main() {
    operator+(1, 2); // error
}
```

You cannot call builtin operators *by name*. You can only call them by operator. Moreover, just using the operator is easier to read anyway - so just do that. Use `+`. (Also, in one part of your code, you're using `op` instead of what presumably should be `operator+`).

---

Here's a reduced example of the second problem:

```
template <typename T>
struct X {
    template<typename U>
    U apply(std::function<U(T)> f);
};

int main() {
    X<int>{}.apply([](int ){return 2.0;}); // error
}
```

Basically, *deducing* a `std::function` is almost always wrong. This lambda **is not** a `std::function`, it **is not** a `std::function<double(int)>`. What you want to do, almost always, is deduce an arbitrary callable, and then use a metafunction to determine the result:

```
template <typename T>
struct X {
    template <typename F, typename U = std::invoke_result_t<F&, T>>
    U apply(F f);
};
```

Comment: `Expected<U>` not `U`.

Comment: Okay, sorry I have been really flustered with all of this as this is my first time taking on a problem beyond the scope of my abilities. So thank you for your answer. Can you please explain to mean when you say the lambda is not a `std::function`? I thought I was trying to capture the results of that function.

Comment: @Sailanarmo I mean just that. A lambda is not a `std::function`. For the right parameters types, you can construct a `std::function` from a lambda - but that isn't the same thing. In the same way that a `const char*` is not a `std::basic_string<char>`, but you can construct a `std::basic_string<char>` from a `const char*`.

Comment: @Sailanarmo `std::function` is for places where you *need* type erasure. This is not one of those places, so you shouldn't even think about using it.

Comment: @Sailanarmo Oh yeah, that's a typo. Should be `T` of course.

Comment: That's what I thought. Another question for you, should I be applying Angew's suggestion combined with yours?

Comment: @Sailanarmo You should not use `std::function` here.

Comment: @Barry Correct, but even with your changes with changing the Templates to how you suggested still gives me errors. But I believe that is because of my operator overloading staying the same. Where as you and Angew have suggested that I change it to a more logical `a+b` so to say. So I need to change more than just the `std::function` correct?

Comment: @Sailanarmo I have no idea what that meant. I pointed out two problems with your code, fix them.

Answer (score 3):

First off: In general, if you're getting too many errors, simplify your test case by leaving out some code until you're down to one problem in the code (that could still be reported as multiple errors, though). Either you will understand that error, or you will have a concrete thing to ask about. In this case, this would mean starting with just one overload of `operator +`, with no `operator <<`.

---

Now to your code: there are multiple issues. First off, why are you calling `operator+ (a, b)` instead of the more logical `a + b`? This actually causes the error you've mentioned explicitly in the question, because there's not `operator+` function taking two `double`s: the built-in operator `+` is not a function and cannot be called as such.

The second problem is that the template parameter `U` of `apply` cannot be deduced from lambda expressions, because the type of a lambda expression is not `std::function`. Which means you have to provide an explicit template argument for it:

```
return t.template apply<decltype(std::declval<T>() + v)>([&](T myT){return myT + v;});
```

This change needs to happen in all 3 overloads of `operator +` (I assume the unknown `op` in the 3rd overload is a weird typo and should actually also be calling `+`).

Notice the need for the `template` keyword before `apply`, because it's used in a dependent context.

Note that [Barry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370054/1782465) provides a better approach to this by getting rid of `std::function` altogether.

Finally, you're missing `#include <iostream>`.

With all these changes in place, your code [[works]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64b86d65b1969be0).

Comment: `apply` shouldn't take a std function in the first place; deducing a type erasure classes type is code smell and breaks the code here

Comment: @Yakk True indeed. However, it does allow easy access to the return type. I see an answer addressing that has been posted in the meantime, though.

Comment: Okay, so this definitely fixed all of my errors. And your explanation of `operator+` definitely helped me out a ton. Why is it that `apply` shouldn't take a `std::function`? If I use your code it seems to like it just fine with the way it is.

Comment: @Sailanarmo I believe Barry explained that in a comment. I will offer an alternative wording: your `apply` needs a function object to work. There is no reason to force that object to be of type `std::function`; *any* callable object (such as a lambda) will do.